# regex to find html class name

Tags: html, regex

I have the following html code :

```
<aside id="side">
    <a class="active" href="#!"> some text <a>
    <a href="#!"> some text <a>
    <p> active </p>
</aside>
```

I am looking for a regex that only finds the 'active' string that is inside `<aside id="side"></aside>` and also 'active' should be value of class and something like `<p> active </p>`  should not be match.

I try to use :

```
<aside.*[\s\S\n]class="active".*</aside>
```

but I dont find any match.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
/class="\w*\W*active\W*\w*"/
```

Example

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your regex is that the `.` in `.*` does not catch newlines. A JavaScript regex has no modifier to have newlines included in `.`, but you can use `[\s\S]*` as a workaround. The workaround skips over all whitespace and non-whitespace.

Here is a working code snipped that demonstrates that:

```js
var html1 = 
  '<aside id="side">\n' +
  '    <a class="active" href="#!"> some text <a>\n' +
  '    <a href="#!"> some text <a>\n' +
  '    <p> active </p>\n' +
  '</aside>';
var html2 = 
  '<bside id="side">\n' +
  '    <a class="active" href="#!"> some text <a>\n' +
  '    <a href="#!"> some text <a>\n' +
  '    <p> active </p>\n' +
  '</bside>';
var re = /<aside [\s\S]* class="active"[\s\S]*<\/aside>/;
console.log('test html1: ' + re.test(html1));
console.log('test html2: ' + re.test(html2));
```